# Which system on the 737NG decides the use of roll spoilers?

Tags: boeing-737, spoilers

Which of the 737NG systems decide to use roll spoilers? FMC? Some other flight surface controller? Does it trigger when airspeed is low?

Answer (score 1):

That would be the "spoiler mixer". See [this document](http://www.737ng.co.uk/B_NG-Flight_Controls.pdf), refer to pages 3, 4 and 20.